# Issue creating .txt file with long name

Tags: python, filenames

I am trying to create a series of text files with reasonably long names (but nowhere near 260 characters). An example file name is:

```
Premier_League-Tottenham v Manchester City-Saturday, Aug 14 2010-12:45-0-0-410996-Home-Team-2010-2011-30-2015-06-14.txt
```

The code I am using to generate this looks like:

```
mylogprint = "Premier_League" + '-' + str(the_home_name) + ' v ' + str(the_away_name) + '-' + str(the_match_date) + '-' + str(the_match_time) \
                            + '-' + str(the_ft_score) + '-' + str(matchid) + '-' + num_list2 + '-' + myseasonstart + '-' + myseasonend + '-' + str(slot_list2)  + '.txt'
```

However, the file is being created as:

```
Premier_League-Tottenham v Manchester City-Saturday, Aug 14 2010-12
```

Here half the file name is missing, including the '.txt' on the end. Can anyone tell me what the issue is here?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the ":" char, that's where the truncation happens.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow `:` in filenames... (it's a drive separator)

Comment: btw: Use string formatting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are working with files in windows, colon (:) is an invalid character in a filename.

Comment: thanks for replying. i have already removed a few other semi colons from the file name because I was getting file errors and no output at all. i've obviously missed that one, which has created a truncated output instead...

Comment: You are welcome. Its a colon and not a semicolon. :-)